# landscape fixed layout epub 3 viewing only 1 page at a time starting from indesign file

Tags: landscape, epub, adobe-indesign

I am creating an indesign cs6 epub3 fixed layout with landscape only mode, viewing only one page at a time. 
I added the meta

```
<meta property="rendition:layout">pre-paginated</meta>
<meta property="rendition:orientation">landscape</meta>
<meta property="rendition:spread">none</meta>
```

and I also specified the width and height in css and each xhtml file with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, height=768" />
```

I want the document to appear as one landscape page only, not as a two sides book. Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the `package` element within the .opf file includes `version="3.0"` and `prefix="rendition: http://www.idpf.org/vocab/rendition/#`.

e.g.

```
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" unique-identifier="bookid" version="3.0" prefix="rendition: http://www.idpf.org/vocab/rendition/# ibooks:http://vocabulary.itunes.apple.com/rdf/ibooks/vocabulary-extensions-1.0/">
```

See Liz Castro's blog post on fixed layouts for more info.
http://www.pigsgourdsandwikis.com/2012/05/readium-displays-fixed-layout-epub-on.html