# Fixed Layout rendering issue with epub.js Library

Tags: javascript, xmlreader, epub3, epub.js

I have fixed layout epub books which am supposed to read on desktop and mobile/web browser.

For this project im using the epub.js library available on Git,

github.com/futurepress/epub.js

but when i load my epub file , it gives some errors as in this image

http://tinypic.com/r/le5oy/8

which i don't understand, when i change

```
 <meta property="rendition:layout">pre-paginated</meta> to 

 <meta property="rendition:layout">reflowable</meta>
```

in my content.opf file
it renders it as like in this image http://tinypic.com/r/10qyrg4/8.

I dont want my text in book jump from one page to another, they should be fixed, and images as well.

Could any one please point me in the right direction to resolve this issue,

Please add comment if you need more information to dig into it

Thanks for your time,

/Karan

Comment: when i change meta property, all my book content(i mean each page (1,2,3,4)) renders only one side of the reader layout.

Comment: Are you basing your code on their fixed-layout example (http://futurepress.github.io/epub.js/examples/fixed.html)?  Viewing source on that may be helpful.

Comment: Still No luck , i followed all meta property settings,even there is similler question to this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440784/landscape-fixed-layout-epub-3-viewing-only-1-page-at-a-time-starting-from-indesi

Answer (score 0):

Why to change the rendition layout: pre-paginated to reflowable.

Beause Pre-paginated means - Fixed Layout Format.
       Reflowable means - Normal text epub.